# Ambiguous column name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image: []][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQimv.png)

```
CREATE VIEW planView  
    SELECT 
        planID, planName, cost, quota, maxSpeed, shapedSpeed, typeID, typeName  
    FROM 
        Plans AS p 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        accessType AS a ON p.typeID = a.typeID;  
GO
```

This keeps giving me error message, I tried to make two typeID equal to each other but still nothing

Comment: You should be explicit about which table you are selecting columns from. For example, `SELECT p.typeID, ...`

Comment: Here typeid column is the issue. Both table contains typeid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a common column in your tables. It is ambiguous for SQL Server, because it does not know which table this column belongs to.

For instance if you have `cost` both in `plan` , and `accessType`  table, then it gets confused about what it should return - `plan.cost` or `accessType.cost` ?

**Solution:**

Go to your `select` line

```
SELECT planID, planName, cost, quota, maxSpeed, shapedSpeed, typeID, typeName
```

and specify the name of table using `.` operator

I guess the problem comes from

```
typeID
```

in the select because, you have used the `Left outer join` so, the values of the `typeID` in both tables are not the same always.

Answer (score 2):

You can write like this :

```
CREATE VIEW planView  
    SELECT 
        planID, planName, cost, quota, maxSpeed, shapedSpeed, a.typeID, typeName  
    FROM 
        Plans AS p 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        accessType AS a ON p.typeID = a.typeID;  
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
CREATE VIEW planView  
SELECT p.planID, p.planName, p.cost, p.quota, p.maxSpeed, p.shapedSpeed, a.typeID, a.typeName  
FROM Plans AS p LEFT OUTER JOIN accessType AS a  
ON p.typeID = a.typeID;  
GO
```

Your query should be like this.

Comment: we don't know which field belongs to which table

Comment: Type ID is the PK for accessType and the FK for Plans. your solution works, thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help. Don't forget to accept this as an answer @ggwp